# Why is this subclass of `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` not generating random variates in the correct range?

Tags: python, random, scipy

I have the following subclass of `scipy.stats.rv_continuous`:

```
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
import math

class Distribution(rv_continuous):
    def _cdf(self, x, a, b, mu):
        return (
            math.erf(x/(math.sqrt(2)*a)) + \
            math.erf((x - mu)/(math.sqrt(2)*b)) \
            ) / 2 + math.erf(mu/(math.sqrt(2)*b)) / 2

distribution = Distribution(a = 0, b = float('inf'))
```

As far as I can tell, everything is setup correctly (I've checked the math and it is also correct). However, for some reason, it only wants to generate values between `0` and `mu`, rather than the expected `0` and `inf` as *explicitly* specified. For example, here are 50 points generated with `distribution.rvs(3, 1.6, 10)` (along with the PDF):

[image]

and here's an example with `distribution.rvs(0.6, 0.4, 4.85)`:

[image]

Why is my distribution 'capped' at `mu`? Have I setup my `rv_continuous` subclass wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation of the CDF is not correct.  Consider:

```
In [188]: distribution.cdf(25, 3, 16., 10)
Out[188]: 1.059763759070757

In [189]: distribution.cdf(40, 3, 16., 10)
Out[189]: 1.203618109186038
```

Those values are not correct.  The CDF (which you implemented in the `_cdf` method) must not exceed 1.0.

Comment: That's odd, I must have messed up when I copied the formula. I verified from paper to wolfram alpha that the CDF approaches 1 asymptotically. I'll check how I wrote it again. Thanks for the help!

Comment: My suggested correction was not correct! I removed it.